# How do you configure vi/vim to do autocomplete for php on ubuntu 14?

Tags: vim-plugin

I understand that there are a few solutions out there
but I'm looking for the best solution available.
I tried a few and wasn't successful.
I need a tutorial from start to finish please.
Thanks,
Josh